# Hierarchically determine if user is in role (many-to-many) by using recursive common table expression in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Consider the following data in an SQL database. By looking at the first row in `Objects_In_Roles` you can see that:

> an object of type `user` with id `1` is in a `role` with roleid `4` (rolename: Level* 4).

**note: Level is just a name, it's not neccessarily a hierarchical level*

By looking at the other data in `Objects_In_Roles` you can see that the `Level 4` role is related to the `Level 3` role. The `Level 3` role is related to `Level 2` role, and finally the `Level 2` role is related to the `User` role.

**Is it possible to create a query (using [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)) that determines that `Fred` is related to the `User` role?**

**Users**

```
| userid | username |
+========+==========+
|   1    |  Fred    |
+--------+----------+
```

**Roles**

```
| roleid | rolename |
+========+==========+
|   1    |  User    |
|   2    |  Level 2 |
|   3    |  Level 3 |
|   4    |  Level 4 |
+--------+----------+
```

**Objects_In_Roles**

```
| objectid | objecttype | roleid |
+==========+============+========+
|    1     |   user     |   4    |
|    4     |   role     |   3    |
|    3     |   role     |   2    |
|    2     |   role     |   1    |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all the roles that any object has Hierarchically. Try the following:

```
DECLARE @ObjectId INT, @ObjectType VARCHAR(10)
SET @ObjectId = 1
SET @ObjectType = 'User';

WITH Tree AS
(
    SELECT A.*
    FROM Objects_In_Roles A
    WHERE A.ObjectId = @ObjectId AND A.ObjectType = @ObjectType
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.*
    FROM Tree A
    JOIN Objects_In_Roles B
    ON A.RoleId = B.ObjectId AND B.ObjectType = 'role'
)

SELECT *
FROM Tree
```

In the example above, you are gonna list all the roleId that are linked hierarchically to the user Fred.